# ls (list) not showing all the files

Tags: command-line, directory, ls

A few days ago I was trying to see a few files in a directory after trying the `ls` command, and noticed some of them were missing. After retrying the command all files showed up. However this same issue happened again
(see `anti_pd1_pt9.sam`, showing up on the second `ls`, but not in the first, last line)

[image]

It apparently knows there is something there (because of the size of the directory is the same in all listings) but it doos not show all of them.

It's not an enormous problem, because when I run it again it all shows up, but the thing is that I will need to always run 2 `ls` and compare both to see if anything is missing :/

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: It is not possible that e.g. `anti_pd1_pt9.sam` was still not completely copied into that folder when you ran `ls -l -h` the first time? It seems unlikely we are seeing a bug here.

Comment: Same size could be that it was still hidden because the copying was almost completed. E.g. when `rsync` copies a file, it create a hidden file, and only when the transfer is complete it will rename it and you can see it with `ls`.

Comment: All the files were already there, the last modification on the folder was about 1PM here, and I made this post about 11PM, after trying the `ls`. I have even turned off the PC in the meantime :/.